# slide my webview to right on thumb movememnt

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, steroids

Using appgyvers steroids.js and I am not sure how can I move between the views using thumb movement instead of clicking on the tabs or navigation menu. Can someone direct me to an article or an example or code?
very very new to steroids.js
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppGyver employee here! There is currently no native support for changing between WebViews with a slide motion, but I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AppGyver/scanner/issues/46) on the subject that you can follow.

Also, for image galleries etc. there are plenty of CSS/JS solutions that work alright, e.g. http://swipejs.com/ or http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-angularjs-photo-slider-pt-2-ngtouch/